# Borel measure absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

Is there a non-zero Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$, absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, such that $\mu (U)$ is integer for every open set $U$? Counterexample or Proof?

I have no idea how to approach.

Comment: Welcome to math SE! I edited your first post a little bit, but I leave it to you to formulate your request ("If yes, give an example. If no, give a proof.") to the community less mandatory, by clicking on 'edit' in the lower left.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure then $\mu (E)$ approaches 0 as Lebesgue measure of E approaches 0. Being integer valued it follows that all sufficiently small intervals have measure 0 under $\mu$. Hence $\mu$ is the zero measure.

Comment: The conclusion follows from countable additivity?

Comment: Yes, cover $\mathbb R$ by a sequence of intervals of small length and apply countable additivity

Comment: Sry for my foolishness, but could you elaborate more on how to cover R b y a sequence of sufficiently small intervals? Thanks.

Comment: Could that be let An=(-nƐ,nƐ), Bn=An\An-1, and use {Bn} to cover R?

Comment: $[n\epsilon, (n+1)\epsilon)$ n varying over all integers, for example.